# WP7 progressBar with gradient foreground behavior

Tags: windows-phone-7, progress-bar, gradient

I was thinking how to explain this. Better with a image:

http://www.foxandxss.net/stuff/progressBar.png

I want a progressBar with that gradient.

The first one is when the value is 100. The progress bar is full and it show the whole gradient.

But when the progressbar's value is 50, I get the second result. a 50% filled bar with the whole gradient.

What I want to archieve is the third one, when the bar's value is 50, the gradient has to be 50% also.

How can I archieve that? Opacity mask? (First guess but maybe I'm wrong).

Well, I appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way could be to have the entire gradient bar, like in image 1, and simply move the black bar across towards the right. This will give the illusion that the gradient bar is growing when really, it's just 'uncovering' the gradient bar.

On a side note, you should be careful with gradients as WP7 devices display a lot of banding. You could add dither to reduce the banding. I think I heard that the Mango update fixes this, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: That is one of my ideas, the background is the gradient and i just fill it with black. The problem is that I want it to go from 100 to 0, AKA from right to left and I din't see any way to fill the bar from the right. OTOH, I have to check the banding thing. Thanks.

Comment: My ideas was to simply fake it. You could have a black Rectangle object and translate it to the right and delete it once it's completed.

Comment: Is funny keyboardP, i was thinking on a rectangle to fake it, but I asked to me.. how I fake it with a rectangle?, yeah, translating it (or growing it) is fair enough.

Comment: Will you be translating/growing it often, or is it just for a load screen? If you'll do it often, you'd probably want to use the rectangle's transform. If it's just for load screens, you can get away with `Canvas.SetLeft()`.

Comment: Is for a timer, I have a timer of 5,10,20,25 minutes and I want a progress bar that shows the remaining time.

Comment: You should be able to get away with using `Canvas.SetLeft(blackBar, Canvas.GetLeft(blackBar)+5);` `5` is how much you want to move it each time. So, when you want to update your bar, use that function and it should move to the right by 5 pixels. `blackBar` is your rectangle object that covers the gradient.

Comment: I think that will not work, because I don't know how many pixels per tick. My idea was to make the rectangle's grow X pixels width in 25 minutes. Well I think that I can move the rectangle from X to Y in Z minutes too. Anyway keyboardP, I have to mark the answer as correct :P

Comment: No problem. If you have another question specific to the moving, feel free to post it.